# Questions about SignalR Connection

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, .net-6.0, signalr-hub

All,

I am using SignalR (.net 6) and have couple of questions about SignalR Connections (specifically SignalR connections that use web sockets):

**Q #1)**
If the SignalR client crashes, will SignalR server dispose the underlying connection automatically for me (and the OnDisconnectedAsync() event will be fired)?
The idea is to dispose client resources (on the server, resource ex: NHibernate session) that are tied to each connection.

My Tests Indicate (on local machine, both server and client):

I tried to simulate this scenario where I had a running client which then I shut down with Task manager and the minute Windows released resources for the process, the SignalR server somehow detected that connection was lost and released the connection and OnDisconnectedAsync() was called. I am not sure if my test was sufficient for this use case (client crash). I am curious of how did the server know, was it the fact the maybe the finalizer for client connection ran?

**Q #2)** If the current connection between client and server is broken or interrupted and SignalR needs to reconnect, and it successfully reconnects, does it use the same connection (with the same connection ID/same web socket) or does it attempt create new connection (tied to a new web socket)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=dotnet

The server considers the client disconnected if it hasn't received a message (including keep-alive) in this interval. It could take longer than this timeout interval for the client to be marked disconnected due to how this is implemented. The recommended value is double the KeepAliveInterval value.

2. It assigns a new connection id. Consider using other data to track which user is it, eg. Checking in the on connect and on disconnect methods.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: "The server considers the client disconnected if it hasn't received a message (including keep-alive) in this interval." -I could not verify this. I have overridden OnConnectedAsync(), OnDisconnectedAsync() in my hub and added log statements to the server console to trace when these events fire and then I run my client that connects to the hub and then sleeps indefinitely: Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue); All I see that is traced in the Console is the OnConnectedAsync() event, I don't see a trace for OnDisconnectedAsync(); The OnDisconnectedAsync() only fires when I close down the Client.

Comment: Please see the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration enable both client and server logging and configure it according to your requirements . You can also set the heart beat interval.

Comment: The trace is _logger.LogInformation() which is already configured. Having said that OnConnectedAsync() traces to console fine should indicate that the same log statement (in OnDisconnectedAsync()) should also trace. Nevertheless, I enabled debug trace on the server just to see if I get more information, but I get nothing about disconnects. Actually, last statement that appears in console is what I put in OnConnectedAsync().

Comment: This is interesting: ClientTimeoutInterval - The server considers the client disconnected if it hasn't received a message (including keep-alive) in this interval. It could take longer than this timeout interval for the client to be marked disconnected due to how this is implemented. <-- I wonder if this has something to do with OnDisconnectedAsync() not firing.

Comment: By looking at the server Debug trace,- the exception (with message: "Socket connection closed prematurely. The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.  An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.") that is traced when I close the Console app it appears the server holds on to the socket as long as possible regardless of pings/messages sent. At least this behavior is happening in debug builds (both, the server and client running on the same machine).